# new command of a math expression $^{\circ}$C

Tags: math-mode, macros, renewcommand

I frequently use `$^{\circ}$C` for writing the degree celsius unit.

Now I would like to make this into a command like `\deg`, `\degree`, `\celsius`, or any suitable command that is not already taken of course.

However, trying `\newcommand{\deg}{$^{\circ}$C}` does not work. In general, how would you create a command for an expression containing `$`?

I am aware that there is also the `\textdegree` command from the *textcomp* package. Nevertheless, I would like the **C** added as well. Just anything that makes this into one convenient command.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can try the `siunitx` package which has different commands which you want. For example, `\ang{30}` will produce an angle degree after 30. While `\degreeCelsius` or `\celsius` will produce a degree and C as you want and it also has `\degree` command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have the package and tried these commands before but they don't work for me (Undefined control sequence. \degreeCelsius). Not sure if it is a clash with other packages or something different.

Comment: That is strange, this error usually comes when the package is not included in the preamble. Does this error come for other commands from `siunitx` as well or only for `\degreeCelsius`?

Comment: This small MWE works just fine: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{34}{\degreeCelsius}
\end{document}
`

Comment: Indeed it is weird, the `\ang{30}` works just fine as well as the MWE. Hence I assume it is a package clash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are likely looking for `\ensuremath`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\degreeCelsius}{\ensuremath{{}^{\circ}}C}
\begin{document}
10\,\degreeCelsius
\end{document}
```

You could use `\textdegree` for text mode and `\circ` for math mode, e.g.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\degreeCelsius}{\relax\ifmmode{}^{\circ}\mathrm{C}\else\textdegree C\fi}
\begin{document}
10\,\degreeCelsius{} and $20\,\degreeCelsius$
\end{document}
```

---

As the author of `siunitx`, I'd of course favour using that package. I get the feeling you want free-standing units:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
10\,\degreeCelsius{} and $20\,\degreeCelsius$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Funny enough `\degreeCelsius` works when I add [free-standing-units] to the `siunitx` package but not without.

Comment: @PhilippeVanderStappen Yes, that's by-design. The standard setting require you to mark up quantities semantically, _e.g._ `\qty{10}{\degreeCelsius}`, as that allows more control of output. But I recognise that some users want to have a lighter if slightly less powerful approach.